# How to get payer email in flutter stripe gpay integration?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, google-pay

my code is like this:
actually  i want to get the email id of buyer.for this i have print see the log.but i am not getting
the payer email id.

StripePayment.setOptions(StripeOptions(publishableKey: _credential,
androidPayMode: 'test'));

```
   RaisedButton(
             child: Text("Google Pay"),
            onPressed: () {
              if (Platform.isIOS) {
              _controller.jumpTo(450);
               }
              StripePayment.paymentRequestWithNativePay(
              androidPayOptions: AndroidPayPaymentRequest(
              totalPrice: "0.40",
              currencyCode: "EUR",
              billingAddressRequired: true,
              shippingAddressRequired: true,
              ),
             applePayOptions: ApplePayPaymentOptions(
              countryCode: 'DE',
              currencyCode: 'EUR',
              items: [
                ApplePayItem(
                  label: 'Test',
                  amount: '0.1',
                )
              ],
            ),
          ).then((token) {
            setState(() {
              print(token.tokenId);
              print(token.toJson());
              tokenId = token.tokenId;
              if(tokenId!=null||tokenId!=''){
                getPayment_Api();
              }
            });
          }).catchError(setError);
        },
      ),
```

Comment: I've never used that library but if it's not present on the Token I'm not sure how you would get it. Whatever code is calling the actual native APIs(which here is going to be part of the library) needs to access the billing details and email separately and provide it back to you and maybe it doesn't. I would ask the community for that plugin.

Comment: not understood what u are saying?i am using   stripe_payment: ^1.0.6

library.but nt succeded in getting gmail.

Answer (score 0):

With the direct Google Pay API, this field is returned when you request it with [`emailRequired`](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest)

I'm not familiar with the APIs that you are using, but I'm assuming that it is https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/. If so, it doesn't look like it exposes the `emailRequired` property: https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/blob/master/lib/src/android_pay_payment_request.dart

Comment: yeah i am using stripe_payment: 1.0.7  library.Everything is done except that payer email field.

Comment: still not succeded to get payer email.i tried that android_payment_request.dart